# How to make a channel that receive multiple return values from a goroutine

Tags: go

I have a function in Go that returns two values. I want to run this as a goroutine, but I can't figure out the syntax for creating a channel that receives two values. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Define a custom type with fields for both values, then create a `chan` of that type.

EDIT: I've also added an example (right at the bottom) that uses multiple channels rather than a custom type. I'm not sure which is more idiomatic.

For example:

```
type Result struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}
```

then

```
ch := make(chan Result)
```

Example of using a channel of a custom type ([Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2WmxcQ0OeC)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Result struct {
    allCaps string
    length  int
}

func capsAndLen(words []string, c chan Result) {
    defer close(c)
    for _, word := range words {
        res := new(Result)
        res.allCaps = strings.ToUpper(word)
        res.length = len(word)
        c <- *res       
    }
}

func main() {
    words := []string{"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"}
    c := make(chan Result)
    go capsAndLen(words, c)
    for res := range c {
        fmt.Println(res.allCaps, ",", res.length)
    }
}
```

Produces:

> LOREM , 5
>   IPSUM , 5
>   DOLOR , 5
>   SIT , 3
>   AMET , 4

EDIT: Example using multiple channels instead of a custom type to produce the same output ([Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ocvGsen3gw)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func capsAndLen(words []string, cs chan string, ci chan int) {
    defer close(cs)
    defer close(ci)
    for _, word := range words {
        cs <- strings.ToUpper(word)
        ci <- len(word)
    }
}

func main() {
    words := []string{"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"}
    cs := make(chan string)
    ci := make(chan int)
    go capsAndLen(words, cs, ci)
    for allCaps := range cs {
        length := <-ci
        fmt.Println(allCaps, ",", length)
    }
}
```

Comment: @nick-craig-wood Thanks for the edit, hasty submission on my part.

Comment: That's too bad; it seems to defeat the entire point of allowing multiple return values

Comment: Interesting point. It would be cool to be able to do `c := make(chan string, err)` or similar and have the relevant data structures created "behind the scenes". Maybe worth a Go feature request?

Comment: Don't use mutiple channels for pairs of values that need to be matched. Start two goroutines that write to the same channel and eventually you'll end up with unmatched values because of race condition.

Comment: Simple, and genius elegant idea! I thought about an array, but an object / struct is much clearer.

Answer (score 24):

Another option would be to use an anon function like so:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f(c chan func() (int, string)) {
    c <- (func() (int, string) { return 0, "s" })
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan func() (int, string))
    go f(c)
    y, z := (<-c)()
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

Credit to https://gist.github.com/slav/ca2ee333c29b8f76b557c9b10b371b52

Comment: I do like the inventiveness of this but prefer the creation of a custom type for readability. </shameless opinionated comment>

Comment: I'm kinda lost between @Hace's comment and pwaterz's answer. I love both

Comment: I like this as it is similar how map[K]V is ranged